# Qt Creator slow because of many includes

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm working on a Qt Creator project which includes a lot of header files (Point Cloud Library, Boost, etc.). E.g. Boost has round about 9000 header files. Now it seems that that amount of includes really slows down the IDE. Code completion is very slow, ca. 2 seconds until any suggestion appears. Even copy and paste gets slow.

When I remove the includes from the pro file its getting better immediately. I've a fairly new computer (8 GB RAM, Core i5, SSD). Is that a normal behaviour? Anyway to speed up the application?

Comment: My advice is to put only the necessary includes in the header files.

Answer (score -1):

don't include all the Boost libraries, just add libraries you need, for example

```
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
```

Comment: That is obvious. I guess I wasn't that clear. I just included them in my pro file: INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files/Boost/include'. That is already slowing it down.

Comment: How about the boost includes that those includes themselves use?  There is a cascade effect that cripples QtCreator.  Unfortunately I still have to edit boost-using .cpp files outside QtCreator.